# How to correctly specify the path in Link, on the conditionally the same page

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I have a link on a profile page that leads to another similar profile page. If you go to the address of the link directly - the page loads correctly. But if you follow the link from the page, only the address of the line changes, the content is not updated.

Link that does not work:

```
<Link to={`/project/2`} params={ 2 } ></Link>
```

This link is located on the page at:

```
<Link to={`/project/1`} params={ 1 } ></Link>
```

I mean that the fact is that we are actually already on page /project/x, and any change to `x` will not cause the content to be updated. How to get around this?

UPD:
Code for rendering profile page:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './css/stl_style.css';
import './css/app_style.css';
import arrow from './images/arrow.png';
import { changeBg,  loadProject,  hoverText, nohover, TabForOpenNew, openTabNew} from './scripts/portfolio_script.js';


 export class ProjectLayout extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
        //constructor
    }
      componentDidMount(){
        //componentDidMount
      }

    render(){
        return(
        <div id="page">
<span className="stl22 stl21 stl6" >Previous:<pre className="stl3 stl22 stl6 stl23 p5 p6" onMouseOver={(e)=>hoverText(e)} onMouseOut={(e)=>nohover(e)}><Link style={{color:'black', textDecoration:'none'}} to={`/project/ ${this.state.previous.ID}`} params={ this.state.previous.ID }>{`${this.state.previous.NameProject}`.toUpperCase()}</Link></pre></span>
<span className="stl22 stl21 stl6" >Next:<pre className="stl3 stl22 stl6 stl23 p5 p6" onMouseOver={(e)=>hoverText(e)} onMouseOut={(e)=>nohover(e)}><Link style={{color:'black', textDecoration:'none'}} to={`/project/ ${this.state.next.ID}`} params={ this.state.next.ID }>{`${this.state.next.NameProject}`.toUpperCase()}</Link></pre></span>

    </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And Route in App.js

```
<Layout>
            <Route path='/projectList' component={AllProjects} />
            <Route path='/project/:projectId' component={ProjectLayout}/>
            <Route path='/home' component = {Main} />
</Layout>
```

Comment: Please show the code for rendering the profile page including the Route.

Comment: It seems I understood what was the matter. You should not use Link, but the componentWillRecieveProps method! Right?

Comment: Please show how you are controlling the state of ProjectLayout.

Comment: Try this demo https://codesandbox.io/s/rj0vq4vo0p, as you can see the content: current page x changed when router changed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use componentWillReceiveProps and inside that you need to compare old prop values with new prop values and update your state variables using setState,  and it will work fine.